# How do I create a dynamic formula on Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

On Excel, I have a DDE formula on B1 which reads `=server|info!someText.data`

I want to change the formula so that `someText` is written on A1 and then reference it on the DDE formula.  Something like `=server|info!A1.data`.

I have tried to concatenate "A1" directly on the formula, as it is above, with no success.

Some other things I tried were `=server|info!A1&".data"` and `=server|info!indirect(A1)&".data"`, but had no success.

Is there a way to achieve this?  How?

Comment: I can solve it for you but you have to clarify the description. A) what is the RESULT of the formula you want? B) what do you want to do with the said result? What it looks to me is that you are trying to craft an address outside of your current document and funny enough I'm stuck at that too :) If the address you are crafting is within your document its fairly easy.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

="server|info!"& A1 &".data"

Be sure to include all the quotation marks.

Then, I think you might need to use =INDIRECT(B1) somewhere else, if I understand your question.

Comment: Nice try, but it didn't work.  We got an #REF error.